# Elastic search mapping issue with tire

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, elasticsearch, tire

Following is the mapping in Occurrence model

```
mapping do
    indexes :_event_id, type: 'integer', index: :not_analyzed,boost: 1000
    indexes :start, type: 'date', index: :not_analyzed , boost: 100
    indexes :events do
      indexes :price, type: 'integer',boost: 100
      indexes :title, boost: 700
      indexes :description, boost: 200
      indexes :acts do
        indexes :name ,boost: 800
      end
      indexes :venue do
        indexes :name ,boost: 500
      end
      indexes :tags do
        indexes :name, boost: 1000
      end

    end
  end
```

when I try to run `rake environment tire:import CLASS=Occurrence FORCE=true`
initially it generated mapping as below

```
{
  "occurrences": {
    "occurrence": {
      "properties": {
        "_event_id": {
          "type": "integer",
          "boost": 1000.0,
          "omit_norms": false
        },
        "events": {
          "properties": {
            "acts": {
              "properties": {
                "name": {
                  "type": "string",
                  "boost": 800.0
                }
              }
            },
            "description": {
              "type": "string",
              "boost": 200.0
            },
            "price": {
              "type": "integer",
              "boost": 100.0,
              "omit_norms": false
            },
            "tags": {
              "properties": {
                "name": {
                  "type": "string",
                  "boost": 1000.0
                }
              }
            },
            "title": {
              "type": "string",
              "boost": 700.0
            },
            "venue": {
              "properties": {
                "name": {
                  "type": "string",
                  "boost": 500.0
                }
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "start": {
          "type": "date",
          "boost": 100.0,
          "omit_norms": false,
          "format": "dateOptionalTime"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But after process started ,the above mapping is changed as below

```
{
  "occurrences": {
    "occurrence": {
      "properties": {
        "_event_id": {
          "type": "integer",
          "boost": 1000.0,
          "omit_norms": false
        },
        "acts": {
          "properties": {
            "name": {
              "type": "string"
            }
          }
        },
        "created_at": {
          "type": "date",
          "format": "dateOptionalTime"
        },
        "day_of_week": {
          "type": "long"
        },
        "deleted": {
          "type": "boolean"
        },
        "end": {
          "type": "date",
          "format": "dateOptionalTime"
        },
        "event_id": {
          "type": "long"
        },
        "events": {
          "properties": {
            "acts": {
              "properties": {
                "name": {
                  "type": "string",
                  "boost": 800.0
                }
              }
            },
            "description": {
              "type": "string",
              "boost": 200.0
            },
            "price": {
              "type": "integer",
              "boost": 100.0,
              "omit_norms": false
            },
            "tags": {
              "properties": {
                "name": {
                  "type": "string",
                  "boost": 1000.0
                }
              }
            },
            "title": {
              "type": "string",
              "boost": 700.0
            },
            "venue": {
              "properties": {
                "name": {
                  "type": "string",
                  "boost": 500.0
                }
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "id": {
          "type": "long"
        },
        "recurrence_id": {
          "type": "long"
        },
        "slug": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "start": {
          "type": "date",
          "boost": 100.0,
          "omit_norms": false,
          "format": "dateOptionalTime"
        },
        "tags": {
          "properties": {
            "name": {
              "type": "string"
            }
          }
        },
        "updated_at": {
          "type": "date",
          "format": "dateOptionalTime"
        },
        "venue": {
          "properties": {
            "description": {
              "type": "string"
            },
            "name": {
              "type": "string"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Venue is coming two times with additional fields.

Can anyone please help me, why the mapping is getting change?

Thanks

Comment: mapping does changes according to what data you send

Comment: I think mapping will generate only one time. Based on that mapping only data filtered.....

Comment: unless you send new data, es try to guess the related mapping